# Why use save/restore in recursive Postscript procedures?

Tags: postscript

In Glenn C. Reid's book Thinking in Postscript (1990), two versions
of a recursive function are shown.

The function takes one integer argument: if the argument is odd,
it returns the argument; if the argument is even, the function
calls itself recursively and returns the result plus one, so the result is always an odd number.

> ```
> Example 6.5: Recursion Using the Dictionary Stack
>
> /recurse_proc % int recurse_proc int
> { %def
>       save
>       2 dict begin
>               /save_obj exch def
>               /arg exch def
>               arg 2 div truncate
>               2 mul cvi
>               arg eq { %ifelse
>                      % even number
>                      arg 1 add recurse_proc
>               }{ %else
>                      arg
>               } ifelse
>               save_obj % leave on stack
>       end
>       restore % to save_obj on stack
> } bind def
> 2 recurse_proc
> ```
>
> In Example 6.6 is the same procedure as the one in Example 6.5, rewritten to use the operand stack instead of the dictionary stack.
>
> ```
> Example 6.6: Recursion Using the Operand Stack
>
> /recurse_proc % int recurse_proc int
> { %def
>       dup 2 div truncate
>       2 mul cvi
>       1 index eq { %ifelse
>               % even number
>               1 add recurse_proc
>       } if
> } bind def
> 2 recurse_proc
> ```

My question is: what is the point of the `save`/`restore`
in Example 6.5?  The program works fine without it (if the `save_obj` manipulation is omitted too), right?
Would omitting it make the program worse in some way?

The explanation given is:

> In this example, the memory allocated by the dictionary is
>   reclaimed by `save` and `restore`, putting each save object into the recursion
>   dictionary until it is needed. If the function is called recursively, more
>   than one save object may be generated, but each will ultimately be
>   restored as the recursive calls return.

I don't understand that.  Isn't the `begin`/`end` sufficient to reclaim any memory that needs reclaiming?  I don't have a very deep understanding of what `save`/`restore` do, but they sound like fairly heavyweight operations, which makes their appearance here seem all the more odd.

André Heck's ["Learning PostScript by Doing" (2005)](https://staff.science.uva.nl/a.j.p.heck/Courses/Mastercourse2005/tutorial.pdf) uses `save`/restore similarly for its examples, and its explanation is essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

begin, in effect, makes the dictionary operand the current dictionary on the dictionary stack. All end does is remove the dictionary from the stack.

So 'end' doesn't check to see if (for example) any of the dictionaries still on the dictionary stack includes the dictionary that you just called end for. Nor does it check the operand stack to see if the dictionary is referenced from there. Etc, etc.

That means that 'end' can't decide that the dictionary is no longer referenced, so it can't discard the memory it is using.

So neither of those operations recovers any memory. PostScript uses a Garbage Collected memory model, so you can't tell when memory will be recovered. However, save saves the current memory 'as is' and restore restores the memory back to that point. So no matter what occurs between save and restore, the memory will be exactly the same after the restore as it was at the point of the save. That's the only way to be really certain.

The precise action of the garbage collector and save/restore isn't defined in the language, its sufficient that it behaves as described when you execute the operators.

I've seen memory handling implemented in a number of different ways in PostScript, and the exact action of save and restore varies considerably. However they are not usually very 'heavywieght', because essentially you are just making a mark in memory for the save, and throwing everything after that point away when you do a restore.

vmreclaim on the other hand, usually invokes a mark/sweep operation to check all objects allocated in VM to see if they are still referenced and discarding them if not.

So instead of a save/restore you could (usually) replace the restore with a vmreclaim. The effect would be broadly the same, but it would take a lot longer to execute.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are rightly confused. I think that in the first program the `save` and `restore` are entirely unnecessary from a semantics point of view. The only beneficial effect (on Level 1 interpreters) is that it ensures that the memory used for the create dictionary is made available for re-use. Postscript Level 2 was released in 1992, so 2 years after this book. There may have been experimental interpreters available to him that had Garbage Collection. But for his audience who were using an installed base of Level 1 interpreters he had to target Level 1, and `save` and `restore` are the *only* way to reclaim memory.

It's possible that Glenn Reid intended to make three examples but somehow two of them got squashed together. Take a look at the function *with* `save`/`restore` but *without* creating a dictionary.

```
/recurse_proc % int recurse_proc int
{ %def
      save
          /save_obj exch def
          /arg exch def
          arg 2 div truncate
          2 mul cvi
          arg eq { %ifelse
                 % even number
                 arg 1 add recurse_proc
          }{ %else
                 arg
          } ifelse
          save_obj % leave on stack
      restore % to save_obj on stack
} bind def
2 recurse_proc
```

This still works! It might be said to "use the Save Stack"[*]. The only problem is that the local variables have global visibility[**].

Thanks for a great question! I had the epiphany that this was possible after reading the question.

[*] The exact implementation of `save` and `restore` do not necessarily need to employ a hardware stack, but their action is described in the PLRM as enabling VM to follow a "stack-like discipline".

[**] But, bizarrely, this doesn't seem to be a *real* problem since the variables have a limited lifetime. Even if the names `save_obj` and `arg` were used elsewhere, the call to `restore` would revert them to their original states. This would not be the case if the function made any modification of the bytes in a string, since string values are not affected by `save` and `restore`.